# Solid angle from closed loop

Tags: geometry

I have a function $f(\theta (t),\phi(t))$ (parameterized in $t$ with $r=1$) which describes an arbitrary closed loop on the surface of a unit sphere. How do I obtain from this the solid angle subtended by the loop?

Comment: Is this closed loop a circle on the spherical surface? if not, what is the angle subtended by a generic loop?

Comment: A formula in terms of a line integral over some second derivative along the curve on the unit sphere has been proposed in https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1396

Comment: Closely related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1200781/532409

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can indeed describe the solid angle as a contour integral along the loop, see [this link](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~dif/SolidAngle/SA.htm).

Comment: Hello! The link is broken, may you add an updated reference?