# What fraction of a sphere can an external observer see?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, area, spheres, mathematical-astronomy

Here is a geometry problem.

1. Let there be a ball of radius *R* and let's call it **the Moon**.
2. Let there be an external observer: **A**.
3. A is at a distance *d* to (the surface of) the Moon.
4. *[Edit]* A is a Cyclope, he has only one eye.

Question:

**What fraction of the sphere can A see?**

I would like the solution with a demonstration.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the distance $d$ to the surface of the ball or to the center? And what kind of demonstration do you mean? A 3D graph is fairly difficult.

Comment: @Rory - The distance to the surface.

Comment: @Rory - I mean a proof.

Comment: What have you tried? You might be asking others to do your homework and what is the point of that?

Comment: Are there any mirrors?

Comment: Is $d$ the distance from the surface of the Moon or from its centre?

Comment: @Jack - The distance to the surface.

Comment: Sigh...never mind, two full answers as requested.

Comment: @James - No, there are no mirrors. ;-) And let's forget about having 2 eyes: A is a Cyclope!

Comment: @Paul - Someone told me that *in theory* from Earth one can see 49.8 % of the surface of the Moon. I try to calculate that, but I am struggling.

Comment: Of course, in real life the moon [librates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration), so you can see more, but not all at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Take a plane through $A$ and the centre of the sphere, $C$. Construct the two tangents to the sphere from $A$, and say that one of them meets the sphere at $B$. Now find the angle, $\theta = \angle ACB$, that the radius through $B$, $CB$ (which is perpendicular to the tangent, of course) makes with the radial line $CA$: consider the triangle $ABC$. Then you know the radius of the sphere is $R$, and that's the adjacent side, and the distance to the centre from $A$ is $R+d$, so that's the hypotenuse. Hence
$$ \cos{\theta} = \frac{R}{R+d} = \frac{1}{1+d/R}. $$

Now, the formula for the [area of a spherical cap](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200781/area-enclosed-by-loop-on-s2/1201250#1201250) is
$$ 2\pi R^2(1-\cos{\theta}), $$
so the total area is
$$ 2\pi R^2 \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+d/R} \right) $$
and the fraction of the total area is
$$ \frac{1}{4\pi R^2} 2\pi R^2 \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+d/R} \right) = \frac{d}{2(R+d)}. $$

Comment: This is fine, but for a little imprecision. There aren't just two tangents to the sphere from $A$: there's a whole cone of them!

Comment: It doesn't matter, Chappers is considering a two-dimensional slide through the center of the sphere, and the rest of the cone is generated by the rotational symmetry around the line between the center and the observer.

Comment: Thank you, I've clarified that I'm looking at a plane.

Comment: So the fraction you seek is $F(d) = \frac{d}{2(R+d)}$ - notice that $\lim_{d\to \infty} F(d)=\frac 12$

Comment: I don't understand this: "so that's adjacent". Is there an error here?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco As in "the side of the right-angled triangle adjacent to $\theta$".

Comment: Oh, you must mean θ at the centre O ! I have placed θ at A. You should define better θ…

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Better?

Comment: Chappers, thank you, this is clearer. Well, except the strange way of writing the angle.

Comment: Now, I understand… until the formula of the spherical cap, that you take out from your cap!

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco There are a couple of ways to get that. One is the Gauss-Bonnet calculation I linked. The other (which I remember being asked in a university interview many years ago...) is to draw pictures and estimate the areas of the regions between concentric circles of radius $\cos{\theta}$ and $\cos{(\theta+\delta \theta)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since, $d$ is the distance of the observer's eye from the surface hence the distance of the observer's eye from the center of the moon is $R+d$. (As shown in the figure below, observer's eye (at the point $O$) is at a distance $(d+R)$ from the center $C$ of the sphere (Moon))

[image: Spherical cap visible to the observer]

Now, let $2\alpha$ be the cone angle subtended by the surface visible to the observer & draw any tangent line to the surface (of moon) to obtain a right triangle in which we have $$\cos \alpha=\frac{\text{radius}}{\text{distance from the center}}$$   $$\color{blue}{\cos \alpha=\frac{R}{R+d}}$$
Now, consider an elementary (circular) ring of width $Rd\theta$ & radius $R\sin\theta$ (area $(Rd\theta)(2\pi R \sin\theta$) on the spherical surface then the $\color{blue}{\text{area visible to the observer}}$ (Using integration ) $$=\int_{0}^{\alpha} (R d\theta)(2\pi R\sin \theta) $$ $$=2\pi R^2\int_{0}^{\alpha}\sin\theta d\theta$$
$$=2\pi R^2\left[-\cos\theta\right]_{0}^{\alpha}=2\pi R^2\left[-\cos\alpha+1\right]$$$$=2\pi R^2 (1-\cos \alpha)$$ $$=2\pi R^2 \left(1-\frac{R}{R+d}\right)$$ $$=2\pi R^2 \left(\frac{d}{R+d}\right)$$

Hence, the $\color{blue}{\text{fraction of surface area visible to the observer}}$ $$=\frac{\text{area visible to the observer}}{\text{total surface area}}$$ $$=\frac{2\pi R^2 \left(\frac{d}{R+d}\right)}{4\pi R^2}$$ $$\color{blue}{=\frac{d}{2(R+d)}}$$

Comment: Why the area visible to the observer is this integral?

Comment: Please tell me as you mentioned "What fraction of the sphere can A see?" means fraction of the surface area or something else?

Comment: Alright, It is because the observer is at a distance $d$ from the surface of the moon (sphere). Suppose that you are standing at a certain external point at a certain distance from either surface or from the center of the sphere you will see that a spherical surface will appear to you (rather to your eye) as a spherical cap. You can't see the whole spherical surface from any external point in the space. You will be able to see only a part/fraction of spherical surface as a spherical cap from a certain external point.

Comment: Harish, I understand your comment, which has just disappeared, but why this integral? This integral is supposed to sum what?

Comment: Alright, the integral is showing the integration of the elementary area as a ring on the spherical surface visible to the observer's eye that gives the total area of the spherical surface (rather spherical cap) visible to the observer.

Comment: Yes, *the fraction of the sphere* means the fraction of the surface of the Moon.

Comment: Then I think you have found you answer. Further, if you have any question, you are welcome to ask I will help you as much as I can.

Comment: I don't understand this story of ring. Maybe a drawing would help. I would like an explanation of the integral: where the parts of the formula come from.

Comment: I have updated the answer & added a picture for your clarification about the elementary ring. If further you have any question regarding my answer, you are welcome to ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're looking from above, so that you see a region of the sphere that looks like the arctic --everything above some latitude line $y = c$ (which constitutes a circle on the sphere itself). The area of this "cap" region is $2\pi R (R - c)$ (See below).

So the only question is "what's $c$?" From the earth's center to the eye to a point on the circle-of-latitude is a right triangle; the short leg is $R$, the hypotenuse is $R + d$, so the long leg is
$$
a = \sqrt{ (R+d)^2 - R^2 }
$$

The angle at the earth's center is then $\theta = \arccos(\frac{R}{R+d})$, so the $y$-coordinate of the latitude line is $R$ times the cosine of that angle, i.e.,
$$
c = R\cos\left(\arccos\frac R{R+d}\right) = \frac{R^2}{R+d},
$$
and the area is
\begin{align}
2\pi R (R - c) 
&= 2\pi R \left(R - \frac{R^2}{R+d}\right) \\
&= 2\pi R\frac{R(R+d)-R^2}{R+d}\\
&= 2\pi R\frac{Rd}{R+d}\\
&= 2\pi R^2\frac d{R+d}\\
\end{align}

Reason for the area claim above: the map that projects a point $(x, y, z)$ of a sphere to the point $(x/R, y, z/R)$ of the circumscribed cylinder, where $R = \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$, has a derivative whose determinant is 1, so it's area preserving. So the area of a cap of the sphere above height $c$ is the same as the area of a slice of a cylinder above height $c$, namely $2\pi R (R - c)$.

Comment: It's not the Earth, it's the Moon! :-)

Comment: Why *y* = sin θ ?

Comment: I should have said "the $y$ coordinate is $R \cos \theta$" -- that'll teach me to reason from a figure that I've got in my head rather than writing it down. I'll edit my response to fix that.

Comment: I don't understand x/R, y/R.

Comment: It's $\frac{x}{R}$ and $\frac{z}{R}$, where $R$ is explained later in the sentence. Let me say it more clearly: the map that sends the point $(x, y, z)$ to $\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}, y, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} \right)$ has a derivative with determinant 1.

Comment: What "circle"? You mean a point on the sphere?

Comment: I mean "the circle of all points on the sphere with $y = c$, i.e., the circle of latitude that forms the boundary of the spherical cap. I've edited the answer to clarify this.

Comment: So the result is? The visible part is: **1/2 × (d/(R+d))**.

Comment: Nice answer. But I don't understand this story of map. Usually, R > x and R > z, so x/R and z/R cannot be on the surface of the cylinder.

Comment: For the Moon and an observer on Earth, this gives the visible part : ≈ 49.8 %.

Comment: Demonstrating the map: Here's an example of a point on the sphere (to two decimal places): $(x, y, z) = (.5, .84, .2)$. For these, I get $R = \sqrt{0.29} = 0.53$, so $(x/R, y, z/R) = (.93, 0.84, 0.37)$; this point is indeed on the cylinder that's defined by $x^2 + z^2 = 1$, because $0.93^2 + 0.37^2 = .86 + 0.14 = 1.0$.

Comment: Thanks, Anne, for finding a couple of errors and fixing them; this answer is now Anne's as much as mine (or maybe more-so!).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an entirely different approach, certainly not what you asked for.

The answer is quite easy once you know the formula for the area of a spherical cap (the area inside a small circle {*}). If the angular radius of your cap is $\theta$, then the area inside is $2\pi(1-\cos\theta)R^2$. To tell the truth, I’m too lazy to write out the proof, which involves an easy integration, so I’ll skip it. Anyway, when you divide this by the area of the whole sphere ($4\pi R^2$), you get $(1-\cos\theta)/2$.

As John Hughes says in his answer, you’re dealing with a right triangle, and you see, by making a planar cross-section, that if the Moon subtends an angle of $2\varphi$ as you observe it, the angular radius $\theta$ of your cap is the complement of $\varphi$. Since the Moon, from the Earth, subtends an angle of about $1/2^\circ$, $\theta=89.75^\circ$. And when you plug this into the formula, you get $49.782\%\,$. (If the Moon had been spherical, which it definitely isn’t.)

{*} a *small circle* is a circle on the surface of the sphere that is (usually) not a great circle.

Comment: "The angular radius"? You mean the angle? A radius is a distance, not an angle.

Comment: I mean the distance, in degrees on the surface, that you have to walk to go from the center to the circumference. So the radius of a great circle is $90^\circ$. On the sphere, all distances are measured in angular units, because you’re not interested in the straight-line distance as the mole digs. In spherical trigonometry, the lengths of the sides are measured in angular units as well.

Comment: Nice answer, John. :) And "as the mole digs" is lovely.

Comment: Thanks, it’s always nice to see a familiar name in these parts.

Answer (score 0):

Some already known geometric properties can be used.

Upto point of tangency, distance along axis is *harmonic mean* of extremes ( a property at tangency), between $ d , ( 2 R +d ) = \frac {d (2R+d)}{R+d} $.

Subtracting  d, we get $ \frac {R d}{R+d} $ as the height $h$ of spherical cap.

Using property that surface of area of spherical segment is *proportional to cap segment height* [ $ (h/2R) * 4 \pi R^2 $ ], we divide the above by $2 R $ to get $ \dfrac {d}{2(R+d)}. $